# Convert.ToDateTime in C# behave different from one environment to another

Tags: datetime

I have the following line of code in C#:

```
DateTime dtReportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(_ReportDate);
```

The _ReportDate is an string variable and it's value is: 21/05/2013 (dd/MM/yyyy). So I try to convert that date to a DateTime variable and the do the following:

```
_ReportDate = string.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", dtReportDate) + " " + _ReportHour;
```

As you can see I need to concatenate the date and hour in the format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm.

When running those lines of codes locally it works OK. But, when I put it in a Dev server it throws the following error: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**.

So, I would like to ask a couple of questions. Does this error could be related with any configuration of the server? Why the Convert.ToDateTime works OK locally but in the server it doesn't?

Any clue would be fine

Thanks

Comment: Pass a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Hi Slaks. Thanks for your quickly response. Where should I pass the CultureInfo? At the moment to using the Convert.ToDateTime?

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out how to solve this problem executing the following line of code:

```
//Attempts to Parse the Date using the format specified (the third parameter can also be null)
DateTime dtReportDate = DateTime.ParseExact(_ReportDate,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Hope this help others

Comment: You could also do something like this: `DateTime.Parse("05/02/2013", new CultureInfo("DE-de"))` (returns "2/5/2013 12:00:00 AM") to use a specific culture's format without having to specify the format itself.